# Html anchors in apache rewrite engine not working with NE flag

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, anchor

There is a solution to avoid escaping characters when URL are rewritten by Apache : the NE flag.

My problem is that it seems not to work for me, and I am also looking for a way to insepc the final URL (the one after the redirection).

My htaccess is :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^carte       /offers.php?#promo_code [NE]
```

I tried to reach the adress, and the anchor is working well (http://localhost:8888/offers.php#promo_code => this works well !)

But when I use http://localhost:8888/carte it redirects to offers.php page, not the anchored element.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [R] flag along with the NE flag to send that redirect request to the browser, currently it's just doing it internally. Try [R,NE]

Edit

Try with this rule

```
RewriteRule ^carte /path/from/wwwroot/offers.php#promo [NE,R]
```

That rule works on my machine. Also if it still doesn't work check if some other rule is interfering, in which case try adding the L flag

Comment: I tried that already, it uses the complete adress of my MAMP folder (wamp for mac) . Redirects to http://localhost:8888/Applications/MAMP/.../offers.php#promo_code 
And this does not exists.

Comment: @strategesim look at the new edit in the answer. I've tested it and it works.

Comment: Thank you, it works indeed, but not really comfortable for me since I have several web projects on my local instance, the path from www root will not be the same in production environment. I would have to specify conditions by using RewriteCond... Maybe I will just move to the anchor with JS on page load ;)